# Retornar valor de una clase Python

Tags: python

Soy un poco nuevo en esto de las clases y objetos. Tengo un pequeño problema he creado una clase que reciba datos de un fichero que uso como diccionario para que en otro programa igual en *Python* pueda traducir los datos de un *4GL* a *SQL*:
Ejemplo.

```
4GL    
DEFINE [Var] **LIKE** [Tabla].[Campo]

SQL
[Var] [TipodeDato] [Null]
```

Mi código es el siguiente

```
import sys, os
import re

class FindTC:
    def __init__(self, Tabla="GenPrima", Columna="agte2_gp"):
        self.Columna = Columna
        self.Tabla = Tabla

        registros = self.readfile('Diccionarios\%s.txt'%(self.Tabla))
        registros = self.workfile(registros, Columna)

    def readfile(self, entrada):
        registros = []
        for linea in open(entrada, 'r', encoding='latin-1'):
        linea = linea.strip()
        registros.append(linea)
    return registros

    def workfile(self, entrada, BuscaColumna):
        aux = []
        find = re.compile(r'%s'%(BuscaColumna))
        Nulo = re.compile(r'(?P<VARIABLE>[\w\d]+)\s+(?P<TIPO>[\w]+)\s+(?P<NULL>[no|yes]+)')
        for linea in entrada:
            if find.search(linea):
                aux.append(linea)
                for lineas in aux:
                    lineas = lineas.strip()
                    if Nulo.search(lineas):
                        match = Nulo.search(lineas)
                        V = match.group('VARIABLE')
                        T = match.group('TIPO')
                        N = match.group('NULL')
                        if N == 'no':
                            N = 'NOT NULL'
                        else:
                            N = 'NULL'
                       return V,T,N


obj = FindTC()

print(obj)
```

Me retorna esta informació:

```
<Buscar.FindTC object at 0x000002752BB6EA58>VARIABLE ALMACENADA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Que quieres decir con retornar el valor de una clase? Creo que no tienes muy claro los conceptos de programación orientada a objetos. Una clase es como un esquema, algo abstracto. Cuando haces `obj = FindTC()` asignas a la variable obj una instancia de esa clase u objeto. Cuando haces `print(obj)`, usas el método `__str__(self)` para imprimir una cadena de texto que represente a la instancia de la clase. En tu caso, como no definiste este método, usa el método por defecto.

Entiendo que en tu método `readfile(self, entrada)` se te han indentado mal las tres últimas lineas al copiar el código.

Una vez dicho todo esto, supongo que lo que te gustaría es obtener el valor registros que asignas en el constructor, pero que no guardas como atributo de la clase, por lo que en el mismo momento que inicializas la instancia con `obj = FindTC()`, se realizan los dos métodos de la clase, se guardan en la variable registros, y una vez termina, se pierde esta variable.

Tienes varias maneras de conseguir ese valor, por ejemplo, el código podría ser algo como lo siguiente:

```
import sys, os
import re

class FindTC:
    def __init__(self, Tabla="GenPrima", Columna="agte2_gp"):
        self.Columna = Columna
        self.Tabla = Tabla

    def readfile(self, entrada):
        registros = []
        for linea in open(entrada, 'r', encoding='latin-1'):
            linea = linea.strip()
            registros.append(linea)
        return registros

    def workfile(self, entrada, BuscaColumna):
        aux = []
        find = re.compile(r'%s'%(BuscaColumna))
        Nulo = re.compile(r'(?P<VARIABLE>[\w\d]+)\s+(?P<TIPO>[\w]+)\s+(?P<NULL>[no|yes]+)')
        for linea in entrada:
            if find.search(linea):
                aux.append(linea)
                for lineas in aux:
                    lineas = lineas.strip()
                    if Nulo.search(lineas):
                        match = Nulo.search(lineas)
                        V = match.group('VARIABLE')
                        T = match.group('TIPO')
                        N = match.group('NULL')
                        if N == 'no':
                            N = 'NOT NULL'
                        else:
                            N = 'NULL'
                        return V,T,N

    def obtener_registros(self):
        registros = self.readfile('Diccionarios\%s.txt'%(self.Tabla))
        return self.workfile(registros, Columna)

obj = FindTC()

print(obj.obtener_registros())
```

Ahora, instanciando el objeto con `obj = FindTC()` no se lee ni procesa nada, simplemente se crea el objeto, guardando los valores de la tabla y columna como atributos, y con tres métodos. Lo que imprimimos en pantalla es el resultado de invocar el último método.

Entrando un poco más en el código, en vez de crear un tercer método. podríamos directamente sacar esas dos líneas que no hacen nada en el constructor (y que hemos englobado en otro método en la solución anterior) fuera de la clase, si editamos un poco los otros dos métodos a los que llama. Al método `readfile` lo podrías dejar solo con el parámetro `self`, ya que en el parámetro `entrada` le pasas un atributo de la clase y un string fijo, que puede obtener desde dentro sin necesidad de pasárselos, sustituyendo `entrada` por `self.Tabla`. Lo mismo pasa con el método `workfile`, pero con el parámetro `BuscaColumna` y el otro atributo. Si hiciéramos estos cambios, sin necesidad de añadir otro método, podríamos sacar las dos lineas del registro fuera  de la clase y llamar a los métodos:

```
import sys, os
import re

class FindTC:
    def __init__(self, Tabla="GenPrima", Columna="agte2_gp"):
        self.Columna = Columna
        self.Tabla = Tabla

    def readfile(self):
        registros = []
        for linea in open('Diccionarios\%s.txt'%(self.Tabla), 'r', encoding='latin-1'):
            linea = linea.strip()
            registros.append(linea)
        return registros

    def workfile(self, entrada):
        aux = []
        find = re.compile(r'%s'%(self.Columna))
        Nulo = re.compile(r'(?P<VARIABLE>[\w\d]+)\s+(?P<TIPO>[\w]+)\s+(?P<NULL>[no|yes]+)')
        for linea in entrada:
            if find.search(linea):
                aux.append(linea)
                for lineas in aux:
                    lineas = lineas.strip()
                    if Nulo.search(lineas):
                        match = Nulo.search(lineas)
                        V = match.group('VARIABLE')
                        T = match.group('TIPO')
                        N = match.group('NULL')
                        if N == 'no':
                            N = 'NOT NULL'
                        else:
                            N = 'NULL'
                        return V,T,N


obj = FindTC()

registros = obj.readfile()
print(obj.workfile(registros)
```

Espero que estos dos ejemplos te ayuden a entender un poco mejor como funciona una clase, que es, que son sus atributos y métodos, y como usarlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo y si me servio de mucho esto ya que aun no me familiarizo al cien con Python y Orientado a objetos